# java - org.htmlparser.Parser , need to get whats between the h3's

Tags: java, html-parsing, html-parser

htmlparser.Parser,
I have the snippet of html(see below) and i need to get the content of
the 
there a bunch of these container divs with unqiue id's in my file.
I can get the divs and their inner html just fine. I can not figure
out how to get the whats between the H3 tags

this snippet of code works for divs but not the h3:
if finds the h3 with the correct ID, i just can not figure out how to
get the innerHTML or whats between the  tags.

thanks for any help

```
    parser = new Parser();
    parser.setInputHTML(inHTML);
    parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    lstNodes = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(  new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("h3"),
                                                  new HasAttributeFilter("id", "h3_"+num)));
```

This finds it but does not return the data between the h3's

```
 <div class="container" id="container_2">
      <h3 id="h3_2">Adding a few</h3>       
      <div class="maindiv" id="div_2">
          ...new articles in here jus tto flesh it out.
      </div><!--end of div_2-->
  </div>
```

Comment: i ended up creating my own TAG
class H3Tag extends CompositeTag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up creating my own TAG

```
class H3Tag extends CompositeTag
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You can cast it to `HeadingTag` manually, and use `getStringText()` to get text between tags.

```
NodeList nodes = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("h3"),
    new HasAttributeFilter("id", "h3_"+num)));
SimpleNodeIterator nodeIterator = nodes.elements();
while (nodeIterator.hasMoreNodes()) {
    Node node = nodeIterator.nextNode();
    HeadingTag tag = (HeadingTag)node;
    System.out.println(tag.getStringText());
}
```