# Extract title tag content using htmlparser library in java

Tags: java, html

Tag on google page- `<title>Google</title>` I am trying to retrieve text content in title tag.But i am not getting an output.It shows Build Successfull and throws output as "TITLE".I need a output as "GOOGLE".
Here is my code.

```
import org.htmlparser.Node;
import org.htmlparser.Parser;
import org.htmlparser.filters.HasAttributeFilter;
import org.htmlparser.filters.IsEqualFilter;
import org.htmlparser.tags.MetaTag;
import org.htmlparser.tags.TitleTag;
import org.htmlparser.util.NodeList;
import org.htmlparser.util.ParserException;
public class abc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Parser parser=new Parser();


       try
       {
           parser.setResource("http://www.google.com");
          TitleTag title=new TitleTag();
          String tagtext=title.getTitle();
          System.out.println(tagtext);


       }

       }catch (ParserException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have posted there is no connection between the parser and the TitleTag.

The idea is to iterate through a list of nodes (including TitleTag nodes) that the parser has.

See [java - org.htmlparser.Parser , need to get whats between the h3's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813705/java-org-htmlparser-parser-need-to-get-whats-between-the-h3s)